# Objective-C Code just executed once

Tags: objective-c, arrays, parsing

I have a function named `queryFeed` which is called in `viewWillAppear` and whenever the user creates a new text. The first row, where the `feedArray` gets populated, is only called once apparently, it doesn't update the array when I leave the `ViewController` and let it appear again, I have to completely close the app and start it again. The rest of the code is executed just fine. Any thoughts?

```
-(void) queryFeed {
  self.feedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.event objectForKey:@"feedArray"]];
  NSLog(@"feedArray is: %lu", (unsigned long)self.feedArray.count);

  for (NSMutableDictionary *feedDictionary in self.feedArray) {
    if ([feedDictionary objectForKey:@"text"] != nil) {
      PFQuery *textQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"EventTexts"];
      [textQuery whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:[feedDictionary objectForKey:@"text"]];
      [textQuery includeKey:@"user"];
      [textQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *result, NSError *error) {
        if (result.count != 0) {
          PFUser *textUser;
          for (PFObject *textObject in result) {
            textUser = textObject[@"user"];
          }

          PFObject *textObject = result[0];
          NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
          [dictionary setObject:[textObject objectForKey:@"text"] forKey:@"text"];
          [dictionary setObject:textObject.createdAt forKey:@"createdAt"];
          [dictionary setObject:textUser forKey:@"user"];
          [self.dictionaryArray insertObject:dictionary atIndex:0];
          NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"createdAt" ascending:NO];
          NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
          self.sortedDictionaryArray = [[self.dictionaryArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors]mutableCopy];
          [self.tableView reloadData];

          if (![self.usersDictionary objectForKey:textUser.objectId]) {
            PFFile *photoFile = [textUser objectForKey:@"profilePicture"];
            [photoFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *result, NSError *error) {
              if (!error) {
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:result];
                [self.usersDictionary setObject:image forKey:textUser.objectId];
              }
            }];
          } else {
          }
          [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
      }];
    } else {
    }
  }

  NSLog(@"dictArray count: %ld", self.dictionaryArray.count);
  NSLog(@"feedArray count: %ld", self.feedArray.count);
  [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: When you say "it's only called once", do you mean `queryFeed` is only called once, and thus your NSLog for `self.feedarray.count` is not executed at all?  Or do you mean `queryFeed` is called and the NSLog for `self.feedarray.count` comes back as 0 until you close the app and open it again?

Comment: Only the first line of the function is apparently only called once. I'll give you an example: Let's say `[self.event objectForKey:@"feedArray"]` contains 3 objects, so `self.feedArray` will have 3 objects too. Now another user will add one object to `[self.event objectForKey:@"feedArray"]` on the parse database, so it will contain 4 objects. Now I want to load the view again so I can see all the 4 objects, but my `self.feedArray` still contains 3 objects, until I completely close the app. The object is successfully uploaded to parse, I checked that. Sorry for my bad english.